# Is the lack of "objects" in Thrift awkward?

Tags: c#, object, soa, rpc, thrift

*Note:* I know the question title is suboptimal. Feel free to improve.

Thrift enables serialization as well as RPC. However, unlike systems like COM or CORBA or ZeroC ICE, ... it does *not* have the notion of a remote object or remote interface in a polymorphic way, therefore all services defined in a Thrift infrastructure are just collections of functions.

[Thrift Features](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/features)

Thrifts Non-Features state (interface?) polymorphism as a non-goal which is fair enough, but ...

As a programmer in languages that make natural use of objects in that I can have functions that return other objects (or interface-references), not just structs, this appears to be a bit awkward in that this would mean that all "object" functionality in a thrift service would have to be provided by functions additionally taking handles as input parameters to define what is being operated on -- a bit like doing OO in C :-)

Imagine a thrift service operating on files. It's interface would look much more like what C has (`fopen` etc.) than what we use today in C++, C# or possibly even Python.

Of course one could write additional wrappers in the target language, but you don't have any support from the Thrift framework, so that's what I'd call "awkward".

Phrasing it another way: Is dropping back to a purely procedural interface on the remote service level an issue?

To give this yet another twist: Even when I use the REST interface of, say, Jenkins, the URL based interface I have feels slightly "OO", as I access job objects by URL name and then specify the operations on them by GET parameters. That is, to me, it seems a string based REST approach can capture operations on resources (objects or interfaces if you like) much more naturally than a purely procedural interface. *It is totally ok* for Thrift to define that out of scope but it be good to know whether users find it a noticable thing.

This is a question to active Thrift users: Is the problem I describe above an actual problem in day to day use? Is it an observed problem at all?

Is this a general "problem" with SOA?

Comment: `Is this [ABC feature / design] from [XYZ language / platform] awkward?` looks like a **Primarily Opinion Based** question to me.

Comment: "*Is dropping back to a purely procedural interface on the remote service level an issue?*" - An object-alike interface is only a subset of all possible use cases. Thrift is only intended to cover the RPC part of the whole thing. One of the core goals is efficiency, so anything that can be built on top of the RPC/serialization aspect is considered out of scope for Thrift (and BTW also for ProtoBuf).

Answer (score 2):

My impression is, that you mix concepts in an incorrect way and then try to draw conclusions from that.

- RPC is nothing more than a [remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). This means exactly that: Calling a remote piece of code, passing some arguments and getting some results. That's all. How to interpret these data is an entirely different thing.
- In an OOP context, *every* [method call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)) (including RPC, but not limited to) is a procedure/function call with an additional hidden argument typically called `this` or `Self`. What really distinguishes an object from non-OOP code is the ability to do information hiding, derive classes and override methods, and some other nice stuff. Behind the scenes everything is just data, which becomes painfully obvious when you have to de/serialize your objects into e.g. a database - in most of the cases you will use an ORM of some kind for that task. An RPC mechanism is on an equivalent plane. What frameworks like COM or CORBA do behind the scenes [is nothing else, they just hide it better from you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms691207(v=vs.85).aspx).

[image: DCOM]

- At least with COM, you are not dealing with objects. You are interacting with interfaces, which are *typically* implemented as objects. It is hard to tell whether or not a particular interface is part of the object, or if it is added by [aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686558(v=vs.85).aspx) or composition. Even the opposite can be true: It may be the case, that two otherwise unrelated interfaces may be implemented by the very same object instance for some reason. Interfaces have more in common with services than they have with objects.
- SOA is not limited to RPC. For example, a [REST-based](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) interface is not considered RPC by a lot of people (although one can argue that point) and does not offer any objects that would deserve the name, yet you can do SOA with REST. And of course, SOA is also not limited to neither COM or CORBA environments, nor to SOAP or XML-RPC interfaces. SOA is primarily about *services* (hence the name), not objects. To put it into one sentence, RPC, OOP and SOA are different concepts, and comparing them to each other is what is called a [category mistake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake).
- How the server and client code represent your data depends on the system used and the traits of the target language. Don't let yourself be confused by the naming of the IDL entity - a `struct` in the IDL is not necessarily a `struct` in code. For example, using Thrift and C# as the target language, you get neat `partial class`-es generated from a `struct`, easily extendable with some manually written code. This may be different with another target language (say plain C or [the Go language](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.de/2011/06/methods-on-structs.html)) and another system like Protobuf, Avro or the REST client of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. Very much appreciated. Not the answer, but very useful.

Comment: I like to argue that corba or com "do the same" but just hide it better. Both support the notion of (remote) interface-references, and, more importantly, the client code deals with these remote interfaces more or less mostly like it deals with local object references.

Comment: I referred to the RPC layer of COM/CORBA, the part that I marked with "marshalling" in the picture. Maybe I could have phrased it in a better way. Again, we talk about different things here. What makes you feel your pointer points to a real object is only a proxy object which acts on behalf of The Real Thing, to hide the RPC stuff away. A pointer into an address space of a remote process does not mean anything in *your* address space. You will not be able to dereference it. [Recommended read](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Microsoft-Programming-Kraig-Brockschmidt/dp/1556158432), but out of print

Comment: [Here's another picture, similar to mine.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms692621(v=vs.85).aspx). Asked where to put Thrift in that picture, one would place it at the level where the "RPC runtime" boxes are. The other stuff on top is what makes COM what it is.

Comment: Yeah, Thrift obviously is at the RPC runtime level. It's just that I'm not convinced that all the stuff above (in COM or Corba) is as unimportant as Thrift (and ProtoBuf) would like to make us think.

Comment: I don't think anyone claimed that. At least I don't understand it this way. We use both COM and Thrift in our software, and we even consume and support SOAP services. After all, these are only tools. You pick what does the job best.

Comment: I phrased that sloppily. It's just that COM and CORBA can be pretty annoying, and Thrift is new and shiny, but when I look closer, I see some things missing that don't get mentioned in the buzz around it. I really *should* ask on the thrift mailing list. :-)

Comment: With the same reasoning you could ask: Who needs a MessageBus, MSMQ or HTTP, when it lacks all the OOP stuff? The answer is the same: We talking about completely diffent things that are not comparable. And yes, sure, feel free to ask on the mailing list, that's what they are for.